# Can I Complete A Cider Homebrew Without Nutrients While Keeping A Decent Flavour?

Tags: cider, yeast-nutrient

I'm attempting my first homebrew this weekend. I have almost everything that I need, I'm just missing nutrients for my yeast. I'm living in a country where this isn't readily available (In fact only baking yeast is available here) so I'm looking for substitutes of nutrients for my yeast.

I was thinking of peeling some pineapple or grape skins and adding them in throughout the fermentation process since I read that yeast grows on the skins naturally, is my logic right with this?
I understand that being my first brew without the specific ingredients will have interesting results, but happy to push through!

edit:
Current setup is 4L of Apple Cider using 100% apple juice with no preservatives, only addition is vitamin C. Also using cane sugar and baking yeast.
Aiming to ferment for approx 10-15 days

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add any nutrients.  I don't use nutrients in any of my ciders and they turn out fantastic.  I wouldn't add Vitamin C either.  Or even cane sugar, unless you want to make a very strong wine-like product.  No additions are needed, just the juice and yeast are all you really need.

If you want to add some wild character from grape skins or fruits, I would suggest including these early in the fermentation, either right up front at same time as you add your other yeast, or at least within the first ~36 hours.  This will give the wild yeasts a good fighting chance at making an impact on the final product.

One final word on fermentation time: You say you want a product within 10-15 days.  This is not a good attitude!  At that point, the cider will still be fermenting and will be extremely hazy and taste like yeast.  To make really good cider, patience is a requirement!  I find that a good cider isn't ready until AT LEAST 5-6 weeks, and longer is better.  Often I will leave my ciders alone in the fermenter for several months before drinking.  They come out cleaner and crystal clear given enough time.  That is how I like it.  If you enjoy drinking yeast, then that's fine.  But also if you will be bottling, be very careful as the earlier you bottle, the more likely the bottles might gush or explode.

Good luck and enjoy your new hobby!